# Read files and merge them JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I need to read only .txt files from folder and subfolders and merge them into one file.
The problem is when i set filter, it iterate only in root folder.
Here is code:

```
public void walk( String path ) {
    FilenameFilter textFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
        }
    };
    File root = new File(path);
    File[] list = root.listFiles(textFilter);

    if (list == null) return;

    for ( File f : list ) {
        if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
            walk( f.getAbsolutePath() );
            System.out.println( "Dir:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() );

        }
        else {
            System.out.println( "File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile()              
            );
        }
    }
}
```

and DirectoryChooser function:

```
 DirectoryChooser directoryChooser  = new DirectoryChooser();
    directoryChooser.setTitle("Open Folder");
    File selectedDirectory =
            directoryChooser.showDialog(null);
    if(selectedDirectory == null){
        pathLabel.setText("No Directory selected");
    }else{
        pathLabel.setText(selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    walk(selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

What do i do wrong?

Comment: Your file filter excludes subdirectories. Hence your loop only iterates over txt files and never walks down into subdirs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filtering before looping and your filter excludes everything except of txt files. This means `list` does not contain subdirectories! Rather it only contains txt files. Consequently, your loops recursion does not work as expected, as the `if(f.isDirectory())` branch is never executed.

Here is a small walking example of what you try to achieve:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<File> results  = new ArrayList<>();
        walk(new File("/home/lwi/Documents"),results);

        System.out.println(results.size());

    }

    public static void walk(File dir, List<File> accum) {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        if (files == null)
            return;

        for (File f : files) {
            if (f.isDirectory())
                walk(f, accum);
            else if (isTextFile(f))
                accum.add(f);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isTextFile(File f) {
        return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the [`java.nio.Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) API instead. It has some predefined methods for walking through file trees:

```
public void walk(String path) {
    try (Stream<Path> allFiles = Files.walk(Paths.get(path))) {
        allFiles.filter(path -> path.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```